# Set relation questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if the following relationship in set are true. E stands for is part of the set, C for subset.

$[2]E[1,2,3]$ I would say this is false as the set contains 1,2,3

$[3]E[1,[2],[3]]$ This is true because the set contains $1,[2],[3]$

$1E[1]$ This seems true as the set contains 1

$[1]C[1,2]$ This seems to be true.

$1E[[1],[2]$ This seems false as set contains [1],2

Comment: You are completely correct. Voting to close because no further answer is necessary. Btw, you can use \in and \subset.

Comment: Thats good to hear..ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, you're "spot on" with each of your answers.

Some formatting/notation tips:

I would suggest using curly braces for denoting sets: E.g. `\{ 1, 2, 3\}` for $\{1, 2, 3\}$. To denote "is an element of" or "E", use `\in`: $\in$, and for "is a subset of" ("C"), you can use `\subseteq`: $\subseteq$, or `\subset`: $\subset$.

Comment: Needs another TU! =1

Comment: thanks for the notation tips